# AQL: Find all persons whose name occurs more than once and who are American

Tags: arangodb, aql

In ArangoDB, I have a collection 'people'. Each person has a name and a nationality.
How do I find the keys of all persons whose name occurs more than once and who are American?

I can run both queries separately.
Selecting all people whose name occurs more than once:

```
FOR p IN people
LET key = p._key
COLLECT p.name INTO groups KEEP key
FILTER LENGTH(groups) >= 2
LET group = groups[*].key
RETURN group
```

Selecting all people who are American:

```
FOR p IN people
FILTER p.nationality == 'American'
RETURN p._key
```

But I cannot figure out how to combine these two. The problem is that I need to filter for nationality *after* checking whether the name is non-unique (because there might be an American John Smith and a British John Smith).
The COLLECT statement however creates a list of lists and I could not figure out how to filter it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, the query to get people whose name occurse more than once didn't work for me. It needs to be modified as:

```sql
FOR p IN people
 LET key = p._key
 COLLECT name = p.name INTO groups KEEP key
 FILTER LENGTH(groups) >= 2
 LET group = groups[*].key
 RETURN group
```

Then, in order to group AQL queries, you can just put them behind each other (think of it as nested queries). And select from the first one by using the name (e.g. groups). But You need to delete the 'KEEP key', because you wouldn't be able to select from the query, if nationality field isn't present there.

```sql
FOR p IN people
 LET key = p._key
 COLLECT name = p.name INTO groups
 FILTER LENGTH(groups) >= 2
  FOR p2 IN groups
   FILTER p2.p.nationality == 'American'
  RETURN p2
```

This one works for me, if there are 3 Johns and only 2 Americans, I get only these 2 Americans.
And again, if you want just nkey to be returned, use the LET statement to filter required fields. Which would then look like:

```sql
FOR p IN people
  LET key = p._key
  COLLECT name = p.name INTO groups
  FILTER LENGTH(groups) >= 2
   FOR p2 IN groups
    FILTER p2.p.nationality == 'American'
    LET key=p2.p._key
    RETURN key
```